# Need to Match Columns heading and Copy data in Sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to solve this issue for several days now with my limited VBA knowledge. I have also searched several forums and google in order to get the desired solution but to no avail.

Please help to modify the following code to find the value matching all the Column headings in sheet 2 and paste the found values underneath each column.

Code:

```
Public Sub FindVa()

    Dim sValToFind As String
    Dim rSearchRange As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rFoundCell As Range, NextFoundCell As Range
    Dim rAllFoundCells As Range
    Dim sMessage As String


    sValToFind = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    'Code to check a valid number entered
    '.
    '.

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With rSearchRange
         Set rFoundCell = .Find(sValToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
         If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAdd = rFoundCell.Address
            Do

                sMessage = sMessage & rFoundCell.Row & ", "
                Set NextFoundCell = rFoundCell.Offset(0, 1)
                'Create a range of found cells.
                If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, NextFoundCell)
                Else
                    Set rAllFoundCells = NextFoundCell
                End If
                Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)
            Loop While rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAdd
         End If
    End With

    rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    sMessage = sValToFind & " found on rows " & Mid(sMessage, 1, Len(sMessage) - 2) & "."
    MsgBox sMessage, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Please help modify the above code to find the value matching the Columns heading in sheet 2 and paste the found values underneath each column. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to work through the Column Headers (e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:H1")` and search the values in the corresponding columns of Sheet1?

Comment: Hey, probably should reformulate this question. What about your existing code doesn't work properly? What have you tried to solve it?
My recommendation to handle this situation, knowing not much about it, would be to convert your table range into an Excel list object, then refer to the column by name.

Comment: @WolfgangJacques Yes.. That's Right. The correct code runs fine only for the first column in sheet2 and i need to do the same for all the columns in sheet2 and the found results needs to be pasted under each respective column. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @ChrisMeurer I want to work through the Column Headers (e.g. Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1") and search the values in the corresponding columns of Sheet1. The current code works fine however it runs only for the first column in Sheet 2 and i need the code to work for all the columns in sheet 2 and paste the found values under each respective columns. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to run through all columns until an empty cell is found or the end of the sheet is reached, though I do not fully understand what you do within your `With rsEarchRange`-Block. Strangely, you copy some results back to your search value area! But anyway:

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub FindVa()

        Dim sValToFind As String
        Dim rSearchRange As Range
        Dim sFirstAdd As String
        Dim rFoundCell As Range, NextFoundCell As Range
        Dim rAllFoundCells As Range
        Dim sMessage As String
        Dim columnNo As Integer
        Dim SearchSheet As Worksheet

        Set SearchSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        columnNo = 1

        Do
            ' Check for Column Overflow
            If columnNo > SearchSheet.Columns.Count Then Exit Sub
            ' Check for empty cell
            If SearchSheet.Cells(1, columnNo) = "" Then Exit Sub
            ' (Usually, I would have writte Do While ... and ..., but you would
            ' eventually run into an error.

            sValToFind = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, columnNo)

            'Code to check a valid number entered
            '.
            '.

            With SearchSheet
                Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, columnNo), .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNo).End(xlUp))
            End With
            Set rAllFoundCells = Nothing
            sMessage = ""
            With rSearchRange
                 Set rFoundCell = .Find(sValToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                 If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
                    sFirstAdd = rFoundCell.Address
                    Do

                        sMessage = sMessage & rFoundCell.Row & ", "
                        Set NextFoundCell = rFoundCell.Offset(0, 1)
                        'Create a range of found cells.
                        If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                            Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, NextFoundCell)
                        Else
                            Set rAllFoundCells = NextFoundCell
                        End If
                        Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)
                    Loop While rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAdd
                 End If
            End With

            If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, columnNo)

                sMessage = sValToFind & " found on rows " & Mid(sMessage, 1, Len(sMessage) - 2) & "."
            Else
                sMessage = sValToFind & " not found."
            End If

            MsgBox sMessage, vbOKOnly + vbInformation

            columnNo = columnNo + 1
        Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: This Code runs successfully only for the first column however after getting the message box it shows Run time error '1004' Application- defined or object-defined error.

Comment: In which line? Did you step through the macro using F8?

Comment: Yes i did.. Code runs succesfully for 1st column and the result is displayed and then the run time error occurs for the second column in this line "rAllFoundCells.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, columnNo)"

Comment: OK, you dont' reset rAllFoundCells and sMessage for each loop, i fixed that in the answer. I also added a check in case nothing is found.

Comment: This time code runs succesfully for the first coumn however from the second coulmn , it shows no value found but the there are values that does exist in search range. I am not sure but i think that the values are getting cleared as a memory from the search range while moving to the next columns.

Comment: Use the `watch` feature of the VBA Editor ("Add to watch") and look at the ranges and values. Don't add `rFoundCell` to watch, but rather `rFoundCell.Address` to see the adress directly. This makes it easier to understand what the macro does and what the ranges and values are.

Comment: The above code runs fine for columns 1 to 4 as defined in code "For columnNo = 1 To 4". Please advise if i need to run the code for all the column that have values till the cell becomes blank, what modifications should be done in the above code.

Comment: I edited the code once more. Replaced the `For`-loop by a `Do`-loop, checking for exit conditions within.

Comment: Thanks for the above code. If incase, i want to search only in the first column of sheet 1 for all the values in the column header of sheet 2, what modifications needs to be done in the same code? Thanks in advance and i really appreciate your help on this.